# VBA If row is empty insert value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm having some trouble with some data there it could occur that a cell is empty. For example we have two columns, ID and value. The ID shall always be correct but value could miss an "value". If this occurs then we should add a 0 in its place.

The problem is that I do not know how to add this to `Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value2)` as this is the only thing that collect all the data from the the sheets.
I need to do this as the sizes of the array is not the same and they must be to continue.

[image]

```
Dim xData() As Variant
For Each targetSheet In wb.Worksheets       
    With targetSheet
        'Populate the array
         xData(0) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value2)
         xData(1) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Value2)
    End With
Next targetSheet
```

Comment: Is this working - `For Each targetSheewb.Worksheetst` - what is it supposed to be & do?

Comment: @Vityata Fixed it. It is supposed to take the data from targetSheet and place the data from the column into xData. But if xData(1) is less than xData(0) then an error occurs because I need it to be the same size, otherwise I get "Substript out of range"

Comment: do you collect the values from another sheet/workbbok, or how does it get there? If you import it, can you just add the `0` after import and that would solve it?

Comment: @krib Currently I'm opening another workbook and get the data from that sheet. Then I'm trying to add the value from the sheet to a variable. But if I try to do this I get the error because xData(1) isn't the same size as xData(0). A temporary fix would be to collect the error and insert the 0 afterwards but I want to avoid to even get to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before collecting data fill empty cells in a loop :)

```
Dim xData() As Variant
For Each targetSheet In wb.Worksheets       
    With targetSheet
         For i = 1 To targetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
             If targetSheet.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then targetSheet.Cells(i, 2) = 0
         Next
        'Populate the array
         xData(0) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value2)
         xData(1) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Value2)
    End With
Next targetSheet
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I'm trying to avoid unnecessary loops. Isn't there any way to add it directly to Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value2?

Comment: @Fredrik Well, I think every other solution will somehow loop through the range :) so it's close to best you can get.

Comment: I will use this for now. Just going to point out that at `For i = 1 To targetSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row` there should be a 1 instead of 2. Otherwise it works great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Filling 0's instead empty cells will fix the issue.
also i get a subscript out of range error on xData(0) line - so declared array with length 2.

```
Dim lngRow, i As Long
Dim xData(2) As Variant
For Each targetSheet In wb.Worksheets       
    With targetSheet
         'Populate zeros
         lngRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
         For i = 2 To lngRow //considering row 1 will have headers
            If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Then .Cells(i, 2) = 0
         Next
         'Populate the array
         xData(0) = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value2)
         xData(1) = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Value2)
         Debug.Print UBound(xData(0))
         Debug.Print UBound(xData(1))
    End With
Next targetSheet
```

Answer (score -1):

This simple VBA code will do the trick

> Under presumption your column value is located in Excel Column "B" and the data is in "Sheet1"

```
Private Sub fill_blanks_with_zeroes()
  For Each cell in Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").Cells
      If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.Value = 0
      End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

You can call it in your procedure like so

```
Dim xData() As Variant
For Each targetSheet In wb.Worksheets       
    With targetSheet
        'Populate the array
         xData(0) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value2)
         xData(1) = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Value2)
    End With
Next targetSheet
Call fill_blanks_with_zeroes
```